# How can I use Google Ads Api on Cloud Functions without specifying the credentials file?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-ads-api, google-cloud-python

I know that credentials are automatically provided to my Cloud Function through the default service account associated with my Google Cloud project. But it did not with work google ads api. I tried:

```
from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient
google_ads_client = GoogleAdsClient(version=google_ads_api_version)
```

But it throws: `TypeError: GoogleAdsClient.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'credentials' and 'developer_token'`

Comment: I don't know the correct answer. The problem is that the credentials created by the Cloud Function attached service account do not have the correct principal (identity). You can solve this by using the credentials to impersonate a user. See this link: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/client-libs/python/oauth-service#add_a_private_key_json_and_an_impersonated_email_to_configuration Also see this link for a class that manages impersonation: https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/reference/google.auth.impersonated_credentials.html